# Rのleft_joinでキーが～未満で一番大きい値になったものをjoinさせる方法

Tags: r

Rにおいて、以下のようなdfがあったとします。

AAA 200903
AAA 201003
BBB 200903
BBB 201003

これにleft_joinで以下のdfを右側に結合させ、

AAA 200901 1
AAA 200902 2
AAA 201003 3
AAA 201004 4
AAA 201005 5
BBB 200902 6
BBB 200912 7
BBB 201011 8

以下の結果を導き出したいのですが、なにか上手い方法はありますでしょうか？

AAA 200903 2
AAA 201003 3
BBB 200903 6
BBB 201003 7

つまりは、最初のdfの2列目の値より小さいもののうち、直近のものだけ結合させたい、という意図です。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

最初のデータフレームをdf1
2番目のデータフレームをdf2
としたとき、最初のdfの2列目の値より小さいもののうち、直近のものだけを抜き出す方法です。

```r
df = left_join(df1, df2, by = c("c11" = "c21")) %>%
     filter(c12 > c22) %>%
     group_by(c11, c12) %>%
     summarise(max = max(c23))
```

### 実行結果

実行結果の`AAA 201003 2`は質問にある期待結果3と異なりますが、最初のdfの2列目の値より小さい`AAA 200902 2`の値が正しいと思います。

```r
> df1
  c11    c12
1 AAA 200903
2 AAA 201003
3 BBB 200903
4 BBB 201003
> df2
  c21    c22 c23
1 AAA 200901   1
2 AAA 200902   2
3 AAA 201003   3
4 AAA 201004   4
5 AAA 201005   5
6 BBB 200902   6
7 BBB 200912   7
8 BBB 201011   8
> df
# A tibble: 4 × 3
# Groups:   c11 [2]
  c11      c12   max
  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>
1 AAA   200903     2
2 AAA   201003     2
3 BBB   200903     6
4 BBB   201003     7
```

### 確認に使用したコード

```r
c11 <- c('AAA', 'AAA', 'BBB', 'BBB')
c12 <- c(200903, 201003, 200903, 201003)
df1 <- data.frame(c11,c12)

c21 <- c('AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'AAA', 'BBB', 'BBB', 'BBB')
c22 <- c(200901, 200902, 201003, 201004, 201005, 200902, 200912, 201011)
c23 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
df2 <- data.frame(c21,c22, c23)

library(tidyverse)
df = left_join(df1, df2, by = c("c11" = "c21")) %>%
     filter(c12 > c22) %>%
     group_by(c11, c12) %>%
     summarise(max = max(c23))

df1
df2
df
```